# Ubuntu hard drive wiped (filesystem not readable) after Windows initialized the drives - Unknown 'Microsoft Reserved' partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, hard-drive

I have a PC with 2 HDDs, which has been dual booting Ubuntu and Windows fine for a year or so. Both drives (sda, sdb) were formatted as Ext4 and assigned to Ubuntu only, while the Windows partition had its own SSD drive. I ran out of space on the Windows SSD and mounted a new SATA SSD drive (sdc) to the computer, and formatted the drive while in Windows.

Turns out, when I opened the 'Disk Management App', it asked to initialize two drives - sda and sdc. I thought this was innocuous disk scanning so I clicked yes. Note that I only formatted sdc, I did not format sda and didn't do anything after 'initializing' it.

Booting back into Ubuntu, I find that my sda drive is not mounted anymore, and it has a 17MB 'Microsoft Reserved' partition at the start of it, followed by 10TB of 'Free Space'.

What happened here? Did my drive's file directory get overwritten by Windows? Is there any way I can recover this, or do I have to reformat the disk and copy everything over from backup?

I can provide more info/diagnostics if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you will have an opportunity to test your backups. "Initialising" a storage device in Windows will erase everything on it to prepare it for use by Windows, after which you can format it and then store files on it. When Windows encounters newly-recognised disks with a bunch of data (or non-Windows file systems), it will sometimes ask if you want to "initialise" the storage device.

Hopefully your backups are not too out of date.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you directly formatted at least one of the drives directly, without creating a partition table first (MBR or GPT). While this technically works, it is very bad for reasons you just encountered. Windows doesn't support ext4, so when it looked at the disk to read the partition table, it didn't find any partition table format it would recognize, because there is none. It then would look for any file system signature it recognizes, which does not include ext4. So to windows it looked like the drive was just filled with random data, so Windows initialized it by slapping on a partition table, and additionally creating that "Microsoft reserved" partition.

Ext4 should have copies of the superblock in several places, which *might* leave you a chance to recover some data. `fsck.ext4 -n /dev/sda` might be a good start to see how bad the damage is, and whether it can automatically locate the backup superblocks.
Research some articles about recovering badly damaged ext4 filesystems, and how to locate the other superblocks. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33284/recovering-ext4-superblocks might be a good start.

Note that, based on my assumption that you directly formatted the drive without creating a partition first, you need to pass /dev/sda (or sdb, or whatever) to fsck etc. NOT sda1, which would be the partition that Windows created on it, and wouldn't even line up with where the old ext4 filesystem started.